# Changing background colour in CSS

Tags: css

I have a website which was writen for me. The following code displays a price on an image thumbnail in white with a faded see through background. Does anyone know how to change the colour of the faded background? I wanted it #73A04D but don't know how that works with the RGB in the following. I've tried changing the values in the RGB part but it still has a faded black background. Many thanks..

```
.imageThumbnail P span {
    color: white;
    margin-left:10px;
    font: bold 18px/36px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: background: rgba(115, 160, 77, 0.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background: rgba(115, 160, 77, 0.7)`

There are many websites like http://www.colorhexa.com. you can pick color and 0.7 sets the opacity of that color: 1 is darker and 0 is invisible

Comment: Thank you.. I'll check that out now.